# iOS Background Task Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, background

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

---

My app is one of these types

1. I want to achieve auto play music when iPhone in background x minutes (ex. 10 minutes to play music).
2. Is it possible receive data then auto send data to database(ex. record weather information) or receive data (ex. weather information) then use Text To Speech tell user weather information?

Comment: for text to speech use [AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizer)

Comment: for automatic storing data. create a database and make a function that needs to be called every X (hours/minutes/seconds) and write code to store data in that function

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve Auto when app 10 min in background. 
You should add  in viewDidLoad  of viewController

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("myObserverMethod:"), name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)

    func myObserverMethod(notification : NSNotification) {
    print("Observer method called")
     var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60.0*10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.play), userInfo: nil, repeats: false);


}
func play () {

// here play the music 

}
```